# WP Admin Redirect Error with latin character in my domain

Tags: wordpress

Hi do you have any idea on how to fix this, my domain had a latin characters ex: sökmojvi.se, when i login to wordpress admin it will redirect but the "ö" is missing ex: skmojvi.se/wp-login.php, and it will give me page not found in the browser. TIA

Comment: You need to make sure your database is UTF-8. http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets. You could try this value in WP-config `define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );
`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i've already tried that, perhaps it is a wp default config.

Answer (score 0):

Add or uncomment this 2 lines in wp-config.php

```
define(‘DB_CHARSET’, ‘utf8′);
define(‘DB_COLLATE’, ”);
```